# Does FirebaseDatabase Auto-Manage its Connection?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

During informal testing with SDK 9.X using a listener on [.info/connected](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) and an [OnDisconnect](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/OnDisconnect) action, I have observed that FirebaseDatabase automatically disconnects after a minute or two when no connection is needed.  The "no connection needed" state seems to be when there are no listeners registered and no pending writes.

However, I have not found anything in the Firebase documentation that confirms that this is a supported capability, leaving developers uncertain as to whether this behavior can be relied upon.  I would prefer to carefully manage my listeners and let Firebase manage the connection, rather than manage the connection in my code using [goOffline()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference) and [goOnLine()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference).

Is auto-management of the connection a capability that Firebase is committed to supporting, so that developers can rely on it working and being in future releases of the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior that you can rely on. It's only implemented for Android currently but if you have no outstanding listeners, no onDisconnect() operations, and you have not performed any operation (read or write) in 1 minute, the client will shut down its connection. It will then restart it if/when you do another operation.

I've logged a bug to get our docs updated to reflect this.

Comment: The code I attached to the bug report I submitted regarding the `onDisconnect()` behavior demonstrates that the first registration of a disconnect operation does not inhibit auto-disconnect, but subsequent registrations do.  I hope Firebase gives this issue more attention.  It's easy to see why the connection must be maintained for listeners and pending read/write operations.  It's not clear what why having a registered disconnect operation requires the connection be kept alive.