# Testing Internet Connection With Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried the google recommended code for detecting connection state given [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)

but what i found is that the listener "looses connection" or stops working as it should ideally.At first it works fine i.e if i turn on/off my wifi/sim data then it shows correctly weather i am online or offline but then after some time (around 20 seconds or so) it stops working and always gives state as not connected even if i am connected to internet.It doesn't change if i toggle my net connection on and off.It works fine if i restart my app but after some time it stops working again.

I tried searching for answers but i could not find any solution, Someone suggested that the listener closes the connection after sometime and needs to be reinitialized.But doesn't that defeat the purpose for which it was made for? 
I also tried using onDiscoonect() but couldn't find a way to restart it.

One solution might be to reinitialize it again and again after a set period of time using handler,but that is not how its supposed to work.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.info/connected` listener reports the state of the Firebase database connection, which is a WebSocket.  It does not report the state of your Internet connection.

Firebase auto-manages its WebSocket connection.  If there are no active listeners or pending writes, the connection is closed.  See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38959244/4815718).

Comment: Oh. That's why it got down voted. Thank you for clearing this.

Comment: Now this question seems so stupid.